# Scrapy and Better Selenium does not respond after yielding the website?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I have set up a Scrapy project in the traditional way, I am using [Better Selenium](https://github.com/dylanwalker/better-scrapy-selenium) and I have installed the Chrome Driver at the correct location.

I have enabled the Middleware, by setting:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```

My Scrapy Selenium settings are:

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = '../drivers/chromedriver.exe'
# Turn off the headless setting first.
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--window-size=1920,1080']#, '--headless']
SELENIUM_MAX_INSTANCES = 1 # if not set, will default to match CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
```

I have temporary disabled adhering to robot.txt. So, my demonstration Spider is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    url = 'https://www.google.nl/search?q=test'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=self.url, callback=self. Parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        driver: WebDriver
        driver = response.request.meta['driver']

        try:
            accept_elem: WebElement
            accept_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                        '//input[contains(@value, "Accept all")]')))
            accept_elem.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            self.logger.info("No such element to be found.")

        try:
            links_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                             '//div//div/a[contains(@href, "url")]')))
            links = [link_elem.get_attribute('href') for link_elem in links_elem]

        except TimeoutException:
            self.logger.info("Could not get the links.")

        for link in links:
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=link,
                                  callback=self.parse_site)

    def parse_site(self, response):
        driver: WebDriver
        driver = response.request.meta['driver']

        yield {'Webpage Title': driver. Title}
```

However, the problem is that the first `SeleniumRequest`, seem to work, as the Google site is loaded, however after loading the Google page, parsing the follow-up links is not working, no error message, no nothing.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong or how I can debug this, as I don't really understand why it gets stuck.

I am using better-scrapy-selenium, as this seems to allow multiple Selenium instances, however I am not usre whether I am using it correctly at the moment.

PS: other libraries that uses Selenium that can achieve the same effects are also highly appreciated. Also note that the Spider is just a minimum viable example. I also would like to apologise to Google for not adhering to robots.txt.